# Is there a reason this program does not return null values despite explicitly stating it in the code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ascii, ebcdic

I am currently building a site to learn more about how HTML interacts with CSS and JS. My goal is to have the user enter **no less** than 256 characters (min: 256 characters), select either ASCII or EBCDIC, and then hit the "Run!" button to print out the character string in either ASCII or EBCDIC. I face two challenges: I cannot get the program to return null values (if the string is less than 256 characters in length) despite stating that in the JS file. Additionally, I have written the code to print out ASCII, but have trouble integrating both ASCII and EBCDIC with the radio buttons for the user to select. Below is the code I have written:

```js
function myFunction() {
  let str = document.getElementById("text_id");
  if (str.value == "" && str.length >= 256) {
    str.focus();
    return;
  } else if (str.value == "" && str.length < 256) {
    return null;
  }
  let a = "ASCII Code is == >  ";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a + str.value.charCodeAt(0);
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 12pt Arial;
}

input[type=radio]+label::before {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input {
  border: 2px solid currentcolor;
}

input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:invalid:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(pink, lightgreen);
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">
  <label for="text">Enter a text that is at least 256 characters long</label>
  <input type="text" id="text_id" name="text" minlength="256">

  <p>Select the following:</p>
  <div>
    <input id="ascii" type="radio" name="encoding" value="ascii">
    <label for="ascii">ASCII</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="ebcdic" type="radio" name="encoding" value="ebcdic">
    <label for="ebcdic">EBCDIC</label>
  </div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">"Run!"</button>
  <label for="button">"Run!"</label>
  <p id="demo" style="color:red;">
</body>
```

I am having trouble understanding why the program returns an ASCII value despite me entering a string length of less than 256. I want to make sure the user can only enter a string length of 256 or above. Also would like to know how I can make sure the user selects a radio button (ASCII or EBCDIC) before submitting their string.

Comment: The function will only return null if you enter a string where `string.value == ""`

Comment: Please check on your if conditions. It will only return a null if there is one condition i.e. *string.value == ""* or as mentioned above by @Sean

Comment: I have edited the code with OR statements. Even so, it still returns the value.              let str = document.getElementById("text_id"); 
    if (str.length >= 256) 
 { 
        str.focus(); 
        return; 
    } 
 else if (str.value == "" || str.length < 256)
 {
  return null;
 }

Comment: I think you are confusing the element that is the input element with the string that is its value. Your test that the value is empty but the length of the element (whatever that is) is greater than 256 makes no sense ( to me anyway).

Answer (score 1):

your conditions:

- `str.value == ""` compare value with empty, did you mean not empty `!=` ?
- `str.length` str is html tag and has no length, it should be `str.value.length`

you need to loop to check if the radio is `checked`

```js
function myFunction() {
  let str = document.getElementById("text_id");

  // check the radios
  let isRadioChecked = false;
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(function(radio) {
    if (radio.checked) {
      isRadioChecked = true;
    }
  })
  if (!isRadioChecked) {
    console.log('radio not checked, return');
    return;
  }
  if (str.value.length >= 256) {
    let a = "ASCII Code is == >  ";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a + str.value.charCodeAt(0);
    str.focus();
    return;
  } 
  else if (str.value.length < 256) {
    console.log('null');
    return null;
  }


}
```

```css
body {
  font: 12pt Arial;
}

input[type=radio]+label::before {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input {
  border: 2px solid currentcolor;
}

input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:invalid:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(pink, lightgreen);
}

encod
```

```html
<label for="text">Enter a text that is at least 256 characters long</label><br>
<input type="text" id="text_id" name="text" minlength="256">

<p>Select the following:</p>
<div>
  <input id="ascii" type="radio" name="encoding" value="ascii">
  <label for="ascii">ASCII</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="ebcdic" type="radio" name="encoding" value="ebcdic">
  <label for="ebcdic">EBCDIC</label>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">"Run!"</button>
<label for="button">"Run!"</label>
<p id="demo" style="color:red;">
```

Comment: I ran the sample code, was the "focus()" part supposed to be the ASCII / EBCDIC output?

Comment: just move the code to the inside condition, answer updated.